# Вход через Гугл в мобильное приложение

Tags: mobile-development, ionic, mobile-web

Скажите пожалуйста, чем отличается вход через гугл в веб приложение от входа через гугл в мобильное приложение? Я использую Ionic Framework для создания веб/мобильного приложения. Реализовал вход через гугл в веб приложении, но в мобильном приложении, похоже, вход сильно отличается. В примерах, которые я находил зачем-то используется google firebase. Это обязательно? Разница ведь всего лишь в том, что у мобильных приложений нет URL, или я чего-то не понимаю?